# excel - hyperlink to sheet based on cell value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, hyperlink, worksheet

I am trying to hyperlink to a worksheet based on a cell value which contains the sheet name. I have gotten it to mostly work using `=HYPERLINK("#" & C3 & "!A1", 1`, where `C3` contains the sheet name.

This works well unless the sheet name has a hypen in it. Any suggestions on how to work around this would be appreciated

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is to single quote the sheet name

```
=HYPERLINK("#'" & C3 & "'!A1", 1)
```